# Header files are not found after updating an existing application with the salesforce-ios-sdk

Tags: ios, swift, salesforce, cocoapods, salesforce-ios-sdk

I've followed the steps described by salesforce and installed the iOS-mobile-sdk via cocoa pods to an existing iOS Swift project. Unfortunately the header files are not found.

Is a reference to a path missing?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Add the `LocalAuthentication` framework.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but it doesn't help. Then the next header file is missing. I guess the global path to the header files is missing.

Comment: and also there are set of framework you need to integrate with `SFDC` sdk so also validate all.

Comment: I just found this article : http://quintonwall.github.io/add-mobilesdk-to-project/index.html

Comment: same steps working fine for me, may be some issue in `POD` setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue:

The current SalesForceMobileSDK does not support Frameworks. Don't uncomment

```
# use_frameworks!
```

in the podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'ApproverApp' do
pod 'SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS'
end
```